# Phaser.js | Remove tilemap before change state

Tags: javascript, jquery, phaser-framework

I have a project with multigame. I have a `menu.js` and a lot of game js page.

In `menu.js` load page, the view is correct. After loading my `game.js` and returning in `menu.js` the screen is not the same. I have tried a lot of solutions but nothing is working. I would like to show the same appearance to the start.

`Menu.js` before loading `game.js`
[image]

`Menu.js` after load `game.js`
[image]

**Part of menu.js**

```
var menuState = {
    create: function(){
        game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
        game.scale.setGameSize(1000, 600);
        game.scale.minWidth = 300;
        game.scale.minHeight = 180;
        game.scale.maxWidth = 1000;
        game.scale.maxHeight = 600;
        game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
        game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
        game.scale.updateLayout(true);
        game.state.start("game");
    },
    start: function(){

    }
}
```

**Part of game.js**

```
this.map = game.add.tilemap('level2');
this.map.addTilesetImage('secondMap');
this.map.setCollisionByExclusion([13, 14, 15, 16, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51]);
this.map.setTileIndexCallback(225, this.test3, this);
this.map.setTileIndexCallback(228, this.test, this);
this.map.setTileIndexCallback(231, this.test2, this);
this.layer = this.map.createLayer('Tile Layer 1');
this.layer.resizeWorld();
```

If I remove `this.layer.resizeWorld();` and return to home the appearance is correct, also I think that it's `map` that makes bad return appearance.

I have tried:

```
this.layer.destroy();
this.map.destroy();
game.world.removeAll()
game.state.clearCurrentState();
```

but always the same result.

If I use:

```
game.state.destroy();
game.destroy();
```

is remove all.

I don't see where is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experienced a similar problem however I found a solution in [Google](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/3359-camera-not-positioned-correctly-after-changing-start-away-from-scrolling/) that served me (in my case) and would seriously redefine the limits of the world:

```
this.game.world.setBounds(0, 0, this.game.width, this.game.height);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is perfect in my case too!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is necessary to redifine the world `width` and `height` after return to home menu. It is necessary too to define world `width` and `height` to all of games you want to load.

In my case:

```
var menuState = {
    create: function(){
        game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
        game.scale.setGameSize(1000, 600);
        game.scale.minWidth = 300;
        game.scale.minHeight = 180;
        game.scale.maxWidth = 1000;
        game.scale.maxHeight = 600;
        game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
        game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
       //------------------------
        game.world.width = 1000;
        game.world.height = 600; 
       //------------------------
        game.scale.updateLayout(true);
        game.state.start("game");
    },
    start: function(){

    }
}
```